# Video embeds work in backend, but are not parsed in frontend

Tags: shortcode, media, embed

When I try to embed a YouTube video using one of the following ways:

- By entering a YouTube URL
- By entering an `[embed]` shortcode
- By adding a video through the media browser (which results in an `[embed]` shortcode)

I am seeing the video just fine in the editor view:

[image]

But in the frontend view, using this code:

```
 $content_desktop = do_shortcode(get_the_content());
```

I am seeing

- when entering a pure URL: the unparsed URL [image]
- When entering an `[embed]` shortcode or using the WYSIWYG editor: literally nothing [image]

Things I've checked:

- I'm the admin user so there should be no problems with rights
- Other shortcodes work fine
- The DOM literally shows what I show above, there is no CSS interference
- The YouTube videos I'm trying to embed allow external embedding
- There are no options for me to check in "Settings" > "Media" (apparently it used to be that you had to explicitly turn on media embedding there, but no more)

Is there something well known that could be causing this?

Comment: What does show up in the source? What's in the DOM? Your embeds could be hidden by CSS and/or JavaScript.

Comment: @janh nope, the DOM contains the YouTube URL in the first case and literally nothing in the second. I do have a fair amount of plugins running, but none that should/would obviously influence media embeds...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just looked at the source of the WP_Embed class, and it appears they are not actually registering a shortcode, but hooking into the `the_content` filter.

Change your code to

```
$content_desktop = apply_filters("the_content", get_the_content());
```

or manually trigger their filter with something like

```
$content_desktop = WP_Embed::run_shortcode(get_the_content());
```

or, if you prefer to have an object:

```
$myembeds = new WP_Embed;
$content_desktop = $myembeds->run_shortcode(get_the_content());
```

See also [WP_Embed::run_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_embed/run_shortcode/) in the codex, and the [source code of class-wp-embed.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php#L58).

Comment: Argh! I had no idea! Running `WP_Embed::run_shortcode()` doesn't seem to work, but `apply_filters()` does. Thank you!